# Recursive Knight Positions Given Number of Moves String Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, row, chess

I'm trying to print a board that given the knights initial position, it show all the places on an 8x8 board that it can reach within a specified number of moves.A sample input and output I have in mind would be something like:

```
Number of Moves:1
Initial Row:3
Initial Column: 3

........
..x.x...
.x...x..
...x....
.x...x..
..x.x...
........
........
```

I keep getting this error:

```
at KnightMoves.move(KnightMoves.java:24)
at KnightMoves.move(KnightMoves.java:27)
```

This is my solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class KnightMoves{
    public static void printBoard(String array [][]){
        for (int row=0; row<8; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<8; col++){
                    array [row][col]=".";
            }
        }
    }
    public static void initializeArray(String array [][]){
        for (int row=0; row<8; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<8; c++){
                array [row][col]=".";
            }
        }
    }
    public static void move (String array [][], int steps, int row, int col){
        if (steps==0){
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            if (row<0 || row>=8 || col<0 || col>=8){
                return;
            }
            move(array,steps,row-2,col-1);
            move(array,steps,row-2,col+1);
            move(array,steps,row+2,col-1);
            move(array,steps,row+2,col+1);
            move(array,stepst,row-1,col-2);
            move(array,steps,row-1,col+2);
            move(array,steps,row+1,col-2);
            move(array,steps,row+1,col+2);
            steps=steps-1;
         }
     }
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
        String array [][]=new String [8][8];
        initializeArray(array);
        System.out.println("Number of moves:");
        int steps=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Starting row:");
        int row=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Starting column:");
        int col=s.nextInt();
        move(array,steps,row,col);
        printBoard(array);
    }
 }
```

Could someone please help me fix this? I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: `for (int col=0; col<8; c++)`  should be `for (int col=0; col<8; col++)` I guess. Also post the complete error message and and a comment next to row 24 and 27 so we'll know which lines cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good first attempt.  There are a few issues with your code:

In the move method, the exit condition for steps should simply return as you do for invalid row/cols.  You also need to store an "X" where the Knight moves to.  And lastly, reduce the steps variable immediately when you invoke the recursion.

These changes look like:

```
public static void move(String array[][], int steps, int row, int col) {
    if (steps < 0 || row < 0 || row >= 8 || col < 0 || col >= 8)
        return;
    array[row][col] = "X";
    move(array, steps - 1, row - 2, col - 1);
    move(array, steps - 1, row - 2, col + 1);
    move(array, steps - 1, row + 2, col - 1);
    move(array, steps - 1, row + 2, col + 1);
    move(array, steps - 1, row - 1, col - 2);
    move(array, steps - 1, row - 1, col + 2);
    move(array, steps - 1, row + 1, col - 2);
    move(array, steps - 1, row + 1, col + 2);
}
```

And to make the board print correctly, use `print` instead of `println` when printing out a row:

```
public static void printBoard(String array[][]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            System.out.print(array[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

After this, you will get the output you expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! Somehow that gives me an error:class, interface, or enum expected. Does that mean I should separate them into four files?

Comment: Everything is in your KnightMoves class.  These two methods should replace your original two methods of the same name.  I did not repost any code that did not change.

Comment: I added an extra bracket by accident. :) Thank you very much. This helps a lot. I'll try practicing some other problems so I can improve! Thank you, again.